# New column based on values in row and a fixed column value in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
Date        col_1   col_2   col_3
2022-08-20  5       B       1
2022-07-21  6       A       1
2022-07-20  2       A       1 
2022-06-15  5       B       1
2022-06-11  3       C       1
2022-06-05  5       C       2
2022-06-01  3       B       2
2022-05-21  6       A       1
2022-05-13  6       A       0
2022-05-10  2       B       3
2022-04-11  2       C       3
2022-03-16  5       A       3
2022-02-20  5       B       1
```

and i want to add a new column `col_new` that `cumcount` the number of rows with the same elements in `col_1` and `col_2` but excluding that row itself and such that the element in `col_3` is 1. So the desired output would look like

```
Date        col_1   col_2   col_3   col_new
2022-08-20  5       B       1       3
2022-07-21  6       A       1       2
2022-07-20  2       A       1       1
2022-06-15  5       B       1       2
2022-06-11  3       C       1       1
2022-06-05  5       C       2       0
2022-06-01  3       B       2       0
2022-05-21  6       A       1       1
2022-05-13  6       A       0       0
2022-05-10  2       B       3       0
2022-04-11  2       C       3       0
2022-03-16  5       A       3       0
2022-02-20  5       B       1       1
```

And here's what I have tried:

```
Date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
list_col_3_is_1 = (df
                   .assign(Date=Date)
                   .sort_values('Date', ascending=True)
                   ['col_3'].eq(1))
df['col_new'] = (list_col_3_is_1.groupby(df[['col_1','col_2']]).apply(lambda g: g.shift(1, fill_value=0).cumsum()))
```

But then I got the following error: ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should be changed:

```
df['col_new'] = list_col_3_is_1.groupby([df['col_1'],df['col_2']]).cumsum()

print (df)
         Date  col_1 col_2  col_3  col_new
0  2022-08-20      5     B      1        3
1  2022-07-21      6     A      1        2
2  2022-07-20      2     A      1        1
3  2022-06-15      5     B      1        2
4  2022-06-11      3     C      1        1
5  2022-06-05      5     C      2        0
6  2022-06-01      3     B      2        0
7  2022-05-21      6     A      1        1
8  2022-05-13      6     A      0        0
9  2022-05-10      2     B      3        0
10 2022-04-11      2     C      3        0
11 2022-03-16      5     A      3        0
12 2022-02-20      5     B      1        1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the rows sorted in the desired order, you can use:

```
df['col_new'] = (df[::-1].assign(n=df['col_3'].eq(1))
                 .groupby(['col_1', 'col_2'])['n'].cumsum()
                )
```

Output:

```
          Date  col_1 col_2  col_3  col_new
0   2022-08-20      5     B      1        3
1   2022-07-21      6     A      1        2
2   2022-07-20      2     A      1        1
3   2022-06-15      5     B      1        2
4   2022-06-11      3     C      1        1
5   2022-06-05      5     C      2        0
6   2022-06-01      3     B      2        0
7   2022-05-21      6     A      1        1
8   2022-05-13      6     A      0        0
9   2022-05-10      2     B      3        0
10  2022-04-11      2     C      3        0
11  2022-03-16      5     A      3        0
12  2022-02-20      5     B      1        1
```